# Comparing Data Between Excel Sheets

Tags: excel, match, vlookup

I have 2 extracts from the same data source both imported into excel. I need to compare the data to see if any are different, and highlight/display the ones that are. I don't know if I could use vLookup as this seems restricted to the left most column where you are looking up.

The first two columns create a virtual composite key so I can ID a match and subsequently used match function to display is there a match or not for each row combination.

Now I need to say if there is a match then compare all the other data between sheets for this match. There is about 15 or so columns of other data I need to cross-check and this is where I am stumbling. I thought I could use just simple IF statement, IF=match then check column D = column D, but I think I still need like an index reference or a reference for the match values to compare with the other values.

What might be best solution for this. I am open to rewriting the whole thing if need be, if that helps with making the whole thing easier/cleaner to implement?

Comment: Can you show some sample data from each sheet and how you want to match? It sounds like you want to search one entire sheet; in that case VLOOKUP would be a good way to go.

Comment: It would also be useful if you could clarify your goal.  Are you trying to see if all of the columns are the same?  Do you need to perform some operations on the values found in the other columns if the first two columns result in a match?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the comments - some sample data would help as well as specifying more precisely how you want to flag rows for checking.

BUT In general, if you have the same layout for each excel worksheet, I recommend comparing excel data by

1. Stacking the data from each worksheet on top of each other
2. Add new columns 'Source' to identify the worksheet source of the data, and add a CNT column that is equal to 1 for each record.
3. Use a Pivot Table on the new data to compare side by side

   - Use 'Source' as a 'Column Label' in the pivot
   - Use 'Key' as the first 'Row Label' in the pivot
   - Add any other values you want to compare to the 'Row Label' section
   - Use CNT as the 'VALUE'
4. Any line in the pivot table that does not have a total CNT of 2 implies a difference between the two tables.

This will allow you to identify any differences, as well as those rows that only appear in a single worksheet, which a simple VLOOKUP would miss. Check out an [example here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/10791482/Sample_Compare.xlsx). Example1 is a basic case, Example2 shows a more extensible solution that can handle any number of different source tables and columns.

Here is some sample data, in your case KEY would be the concatenation of the two columns that identify your records:

```
- - - Worksheet MyOldData - - - - - - - 
Key      Name        Income
A        Aunders     111111
B        Blake       222222
C        Conan       333333
D        Ders        444444

- - - Worksheet MyNewData - - - - - - - 
Key      Name        Income
A        Anders      111111 <-- Diff Name
B        Blake       200000 <-- Diff Income
C        Conan       333333
```

Would lead to -->

```
- - -Worksheet ReadyToCompare - - - - - - - 
Key      Name        Income  Source  Cnt
A        Anders      111111  New     1
B        Blake       200000  New     1
C        Conan       333333  New     1
A        Aunders     111111  Old     1
B        Blake       222222  Old     1
C        Conan       333333  Old     1
D        Ders        333333  Old     1
```

The new, lovely, data-friendly 'ReadyToCompare' table can be used as the source for a pivot table.

Comment: Hmmm, most people i've spoke to said it is simple use vlookup but I cant see how you can do that with multiple columns of data. It seems more like I need to create an identifier for each row (two first columns combined) then concatenate the data from the other columns and compare.

I combined the two columns AB to create unique ID and then done a match but this doesn't help me get to where I am going because it only tells me if value I am checking is in the array.

=ISNA(MATCH(U2,Sheet1!$U$2:$U$32144,0))

Can I reference any of the values of the match in the array ?

Comment: Be careful with Vlookup for comparison unless you know that your tables have exactly the same identifiers.  In the example data above, if you did a VLOOKUP using the NEW data as the basis, you wouldn't know about the 'D' entry in the old table. The method above does scale to any number of columns.  I'll update the example link to show a larger demo.

Comment: Ended up using VBA to do this as I was finding excel based functions were going to end up being a bit clunky to contend with. but thansk for help and suggestions.